# bloomberg API - Field Search Request

Tags: api, search, request, field, bloomberg

How to make use of “category” according to “A.3.4 Field Search Request” of developers guide? The Bloomberglp.Blpapi.dll is from blpapi_dotnet_3.4.8.1., development by C# .net.

I used the following code in order to get the information but it does not work.

```
        Service refDataSvc = session.GetService("//blp/refdata");
        Request request = refDataSvc.CreateRequest("ReferenceDataRequest");
        request.Append("securities", "/isin/CNE1000002Q2 HK"); 
        Element element = request.GetElement("include");
        element.SetElement("productType", "Equity");
        element.SetElement("fieldType", "Static");
        Element element1 = element.GetElement("category");
        element1.AppendValue("Ratings");
        element1.AppendValue("Analysis");
        element1.AppendValue("Corporate Actions");
        session.SendRequest(request, null);
```

I also tried other ways

a)

```
        Service refDataService = session.GetService("//blp/refdata");
        Request request = refDataService.CreateRequest("ReferenceDataRequest");
        Element securities = request.GetElement("securities");
        securities.AppendValue("IBM US Equity");
        Element fields = request.GetElement("fields");
        fields.AppendValue("PX_LAST");
        Element element1 = fields.GetElement("category");
        element1.AppendValue("Corporate Actions");
        session.SendRequest(request, null);
```

b)

```
        Service refDataService = session.GetService("//blp/refdata");
        Request request = refDataService.CreateRequest("ReferenceDataRequest");
        Element securities = request.GetElement("securities");
        securities.AppendValue("IBM US Equity");
        Element element1 = request.GetElement("category");
        element1.AppendValue("Corporate Actions");
        session.SendRequest(request, null);
```

Both are not successful.
Could anyone advise me on this?

Comment: Have you read the section on Categorized Field Search Request (in the Core Services part)? Have you asked the help desk?

Comment: I had read that section, I find that the Field Search Request should be used with the service //blp/apiflds and the request should be createRequest("FieldSearchRequest"), but I still cannot get the information about "Corporate Actions".

Comment: What do you mean by "Corporate Actions"? Is this just a general idea of what you want to get, or is this data that you are able to get in the Terminal, but don't know how to get through the API? If you're getting it in the Terminal - tell us what is, and maybe we can help. If it's just a general notion of what you want... you need to have rethink about what it is, exactly, that you want. Generally speaking, if it's available as field on a security (i.e. in FLDS) it's accessible in Excel or through the API.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. At the beginning, I would like to get all descriptive and numerical field related to Corporate Actions. But its seems that in excel or API, there are only some numerical fields related to Corporate Actions.