# bloomberg API Corporate Action

Tags: .net, api, action, bloomberg

In bloomberg API, using .net, does anyone know how to get the corporate action of an equity?
I tried to get all the fields of an equity by using Subscription but I can't find any related to corporate action. I also tried to use Field Search Request but unsuccessful, the link is:
[bloomberg API - Field Search Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11899919/bloomberg-api-field-search-request)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get corporate actions like Dividends, Rights,Spin Offs Splits and No Delivery.
DVD_EX_DATE for example.
Use static request on Equity for this.

Easiest way to see corporate actions related fields is from the excel plugin.
Open  import data -> Market Reference,Analytical,Data Sets
insert a stock and look in the corporate actions (I couldn't upload a screenshot)

Comment: Thanks, I can get some corporate actions related fields from the excel plugin.

Comment: Everything that you do from Excel you should be able to do using the API.

Answer (score 1):

The corporate action data is not available through the API, you need to use the data license product.

`DLSD <GO>` in the terminal has the documentation.